# Swift .symbolEffect disable under condition

Tags: swift, swiftui, sf-symbols

I have a SwiftUI Image view structure inside view

```
Image(systemName: TabBarItem.chat.iconName)
                .resizable()
                .symbolVariant(localSelection == .chat ? .fill : .none)
                .symbolEffect(.bounce, options: .repeating, value: tabBarStateManager.shouldAnimateChatTabIcon)
                .symbolEffect(.variableColor.iterative, options: .repeating, value: tabBarStateManager.shouldAnimateChatTabIcon)
```

along with two symbol effects. I want these effects to repeat as long as **tabBarStateManager's**
`@Published var shouldAnimateChatTabIcon: Bool` is equal to **true**.
I guess that value **argument** in `.symbolEffect` modifier is only to trigger the animation, but how to disable it on some condition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want the symbol effect to begin when the flag  is set to true and the effect should repeat continuously until the flag is set to false. Then it should stop.

You can get quite close to this just by making the `SymbolEffectOptions` conditional on the flag. What then happens is that when the flag changes to false, it performs one more cycle and then stops. If a small lag before stopping is acceptable then this gives an easy solution:

```swift
.symbolEffect(
    .bounce,
    options: tabBarStateManager.shouldAnimateChatTabIcon ? .repeating : .nonRepeating,
    value: tabBarStateManager.shouldAnimateChatTabIcon
)
.symbolEffect(
    .variableColor.iterative,
    options: tabBarStateManager.shouldAnimateChatTabIcon ? .repeating : .nonRepeating,
    value: tabBarStateManager.shouldAnimateChatTabIcon
)
```

Alternatively, the lag can be avoided altogether by introducing a second flag:

```swift
@State private var runAnimation = false
```

The flag in the model can then be used as the parameter to `.symbolEffectsRemoved`, which allows the symbol effects to be removed conditionally. When the effects are present, the second flag is used to set them running.

It is interesting that `.symbolEffectsRemoved` needs to be applied *before* the `.symbolEffect` modifiers. The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/symboleffectsremoved(_:)) gives a clue as to why:

> Returns a new view with its inherited symbol image effects either removed or left unchanged.

So it seems that a symbol can have some **inherited** effects and the `.symbolEffect` modifiers set them into action. To prevent the `.symbolEffect` modifiers from working, the inherited effects must be removed first, not afterwards.

```swift
Image(systemName: TabBarItem.chat.iconName)
    .resizable()
    .symbolVariant(localSelection == .chat ? .fill : .none)
    .symbolEffectsRemoved(!tabBarStateManager.shouldAnimateChatTabIcon)
    .symbolEffect(.bounce, options: .repeating, value: runAnimation)
    .symbolEffect(.variableColor.iterative, options: .repeating, value: runAnimation)
    .onChange(of: tabBarStateManager.shouldAnimateChatTabIcon) { oldVal, newVal in
        if newVal {
            runAnimation.toggle()
        }
    }
```

[image: Animation]

Comment: Setting SymbolEffectOptions conditionally did the trick. Thank you very much!